# Calculating region pair distances along network in QGIS 3.22.4

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, point, network, shortest-path

I'm currently attempting to calculate the distances between several thousand region pairs (centroids) along the Roman road network in QGIS. I want to achieve something similar to the ["Shortest path(point to point)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#shortest-path-point-to-point) but without having to select each region pair manually.

I tried GRASS' [`v.net.path`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass80/manuals/v.net.path.html) using this text file for start and endpoint:

```
1 16.4836006898 47.5131047372 16.7546593978 47.853451577
2 16.4836006898 47.5131047372 16.2549768535 47.1759942488
3 16.4836006898 47.5131047372 14.99757632 48.0531988991
4 16.4836006898 47.5131047372 15.9022880118 47.7980278446
5 16.4836006898 47.5131047372 15.6468742126 48.162827661
6 16.4836006898 47.5131047372 15.3172361365 48.6431581377
```

but the algorithm always produced an empty layer although I set the maximum distance of coordinates from the network to the maximum.

Comment: You could run `Shortest path(point to point)` in batch mode.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you looking for a solution to this problem: I found that the [QNEAT3 plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QNEAT3/)'s OD matrix worked for me.

See the documentation for more details: https://root676.github.io/OdMatrixAlgs.html